# Jpa association with Enumeration attribute, not constant

Tags: java, jpa, enums

Is there a way to bind an Enum attribute and not enum constant with Jpa column.

I have a enum like this:

```
public enum Type{
   TYPE1("type1"),
   TYPE2("type2);

   private String enumValue;
   Type(String enumValue){
       this.enumValue = enumValue;
   }

   public String getValue(){
       return enumValue;
   }
}
```

And entity like this:

```
public class TestEntity{    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;   
}
```

My entity always bind with enum constant i.e. TYPE1 and not with enumValue i.e. "type1". I could not find a way to do that. I am wondering is that is even possible with JPA.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a hibernate-proprietary [custom type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#types-custom) (if you use Hibernate) or, if you use a JPA 2.1 implementation, with the new [`Convert` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html). Here's [an article](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/06/mapping-enums-done-right-with-convert.html) showing an example

```
@Convert(converter = TypeConverter.class)
private Type type;
```

...

```
@Converter
public class TypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Type, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Type attribute) {
        return attribute.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Type convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return Type.fromValue(dbData);
    }
}
```